# Production build customization options. Vue-cli 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, modularity

I have a vue-cli 3 client-side app created for performance tracking, which displays a variety of *"widgets"*.
Each widget component is named `[widgetName].vue`, stored in `src` -> `components` folder and communicates with the outer world through *getters* and *actions*, as i utilize `vuex`.

**Problem:**

Variety of widgets is growing as amount of different business clients gradually increases. Some clients just don't need to have several types of widgets in their copy of app.

There is an additional complication: clients - are industrial sites without direct internet access. They get their app updates only when our maintenance engineer visits them.

**Desired solution (very general):**

- All widgets need to be moved from a *"widget-indicator"* app itself to some kind of library. In development mode `npm-link` should be utilized.
- There should be an ability to select groups of widgets which are going to be included into production build.

I tried to find some kind of console wizard that allows to make selection of components that should be included into production build, but without any luck. What are the possible options here?

Answer (score 0):

Building out a component library seems to be a good start. Once built, the maintenance engineer can perhaps npm install client selected libraries from disk.

These are a few template utilities that helped me achieve what you're looking for.

https://github.com/team-innovation/vue-sfc-rollup

https://github.com/Akryum/vue-share-components

https://github.com/chrisvfritz/hello-vue-components